# Residue of $f(z)=e^{-1/z^2}$ using it's pole order

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Find the residue of $f(z)=e^{-1/z^2}$ at $z=0$

Can somebody check both methods?

I wrote out the series of $$e^z=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}!+...$$ and subbed in $-1/z^2$ instead of $z$ to get:

$$1-1/z^2+\frac{1}{z^42}!+...$$ which implied that the residue is $0$.

**Now method 2**

Simply use the residue theorem to get $$Res(f,0)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} ze^{-1/z^2}=0$$

However, I can only do this if $z=0$ is a simple pole. Otherwise I need to involve derivatives.

How can I calculate the order of the pole of $f(z)$?

Comment: It is an essential singularity, not a pole, so you're second method is not correct.

Comment: $ze^{-1/z^2}$ does *not* converge to $0$ as $z \to 0$.  Consider, for example, $z=0.00001i$ to see why this is false.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't think of trying a complex $z$